# edge of a cubic graph and number of Hamilton cycles

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I'd like to prove this statement.[image]

I want to start with: at any vertex v, edges connected with v can be colored in 3 colors. so there are at least 3 hamilton cycles. Then I don't know how to continue the proof. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow that at all... Why are there at least 3 Hamilton cycles? Usually this is proven as a corollary to the result you're trying to prove (under the additional assumption that the graph is Hamiltonian; examples such as the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) show that a cubic graph need not even have one Hamiltonian cycle). It seems to me that the result of having at least 3 Hamiltonian cycles was already proved in your class, so I suggest you connect to your lecture notes to find a solution to the exercise.

Comment: (Alternatively, you could point us to the lecture notes so we can give a better hint.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edges on an even number of Hamilton cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287856/edges-on-an-even-number-of-hamilton-cycles)