# undirected graphs and Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to prove that if all vertices of a finite undirected graph are of odd degree, then each edge is contained within an even number of Hamiltonian cycles. (or none).

I know a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph is every cycle that contains each vertex in the graph exactly once. I tried to prove the problem by using geometrical figures with some extra edges added but it didn't work out. I would be really thankful if someone could explain their solution to this problem!

Comment: Interesting question. Context--i.e., textbook problem or research problem....

Comment: By ‘even number of Ham cycles’ you mean distinct cycles right? so it’s like a counting problem?

Comment: I took it to mean that two Hamiltonian cycles $C_1$ and $C_2$ are distinct iff there is an edge in $C_1 \setminus C_2$ [and therefore an edge in $C_2 \setminus C_1$]

Comment: i.e., the Ham cycle $x_1\ldots x_nx_1$ is equivalent to $x_ix_{i+1}\ldots x_nx_1\ldots x_{i-1}$ for each $i$

Comment: textbook problem. Sure, two Hamiltonian cycles are distinct if they differ by at least one edge.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287856/edges-on-an-even-number-of-hamilton-cycles

Comment: This doesn't give the full answer @MatthewLarson but it does get you through a crux of the problem

Comment: To be more specific, I believe you can use the line of reasoning in the answer in the link I posted, to show that there is an even number of Ham circuits through each *vertex*, which gives what you need

Comment: @Mike It seems like the question you linked is exactly the same as this one. Both are asking you to prove a graph with all vertices having odd degree will have an even number of Hamiltonian cycles containing any given edge.

Comment: Well but we do need to be careful @Mike Earnest, letting $h(e)$ be the number of Ham cycles on $e$ and letting $v$ be a vertex in $G$, the sum $\sum_{e \ni v} h(e)$ *double*-counts the number of Ham cycles containing $v$ (which is the number of Ham cycles in $G$).

Comment: My mistake @MikeEarnest in fact these are the same questions indeed...for whatever reason I read to say that the *total* number of Hamiltonian cycles in $G$ is even