# Does a unique Hamiltonian graph have other long cycles?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and let $C$ be a Hamiltonian cycle of $G$.
Call an edge $e$ of the graph $G$ a chord if $e\not\in C$.
Let each edge of $C$ have a weight of $1$ and each chord have a weight of $2$.
The weight of a path or cycle of this graph is the sum of the weights of its edges.
For example, the weight of the cycle $C$ is $n$.

Is the following statement true under the above conditions on the graph $G$? Or maybe there is a counterexample after all?

> If at least one chord leaves every vertex of the graph $G$, then there
> exists a cycle in $G$  (not necessarily Hamiltonian) whose weight is
> greater than $n$.

What I know is that if the number of chords for each vertex is odd,
then it follows from [Thomason's theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167506008705119) 
$G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle $C'$ different from $C$,
hence $C'$ contains chords.
It follows that the weight of $C'$ is greater than $n$.
By the way, a good statement of Thomason's theorem can be found in
[Brian Scott's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287856).

However, in general a graph can have one single Hamiltonian cycle
(such graphs are called uniquely hamiltonian) even if the degree of each vertex is at least three.
The smallest uniquely hamiltonian graph
with minimum vertex degree at least $3$ contains $18$ vertices and is shown in the figure.
This graph was constructed by [Gordon Royle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255784/).
The cycle
$$
C'=\{1,5,6,\ldots,17,4,3,2,1\}
$$
has weight $19$.
This graph also has a cycle of weight $25$ (apparently the maximum possible).

[image]

**Addition.**
It's worth noting that exactly this problem is formulated in Tony Huynh's answer to a question from [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144958).
Here is the very last sentence of his answer "I think it should be easy to show that such a graph has a cycle longer than $C$". The cycle $C$ is the Hamiltonian cycle of the graph and the length is the weight of the cycle in our terminology.

**Addition 2.**
@caduk drew my attention to the following problem posed by Thomassen in the paper On the Number of Hamiltonian Cycles in Bipartite Graphs, page 440:

Problem 1. Does every Hamiltonian graph $G$ of minimum degree at least $3$ contain an edge
$e$ such that $G-e$ and $G/e$ are both Hamiltonian?

Thomassen proved that Problem 1 has an affirmative answer for bipartite graphs.

From the affirmative answer to Problem 1, it is easy to get an affirmative answer to my question.
In fact, let there exist an edge $e$ in our graph $G$ such that $G-e$ and $G/e$ are both Hamiltonian.
If $e\in C$, then we exploit the fact that $G-e$ is Hamiltonian.
If $e\not\in C$, then we will take advantage of the fact that $G/e$ is Hamiltonian.

However, it seems to me that my question is much simpler than Thomassen's problem.

**Remark.**
I posted this question [на MathOveflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/460794/173068)

Comment: @caduk Thank you very much for your comment. Indeed, this seems like a pretty simple problem to me, but I can't see how it could be solved. By the way, C. Thomassen has a theorem about cycles in bipartite graphs in his 1996 paper. Could not his reasoning be applied to my question. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: His result solves your problem in bipartite graphs, but I don't see how it can be extended directly for general graphs.

Comment: @caduk Thank you, could you please specify for which conjecture it is not difficult to construct a counter-example. I posted my question on MathOverflow (maybe you saw it) but unfortunately there is no answer there either.

Comment: Wow, I got really confused and everything iI said was wrong. The conjecture of thomassen (a hamiltonian graph $G$ of minimum degree at least $3$ has at least one edge $e$ such that both the deletion $G\backslash e$ and contraction $G/e$ are hamiltonian) do indeed prove that every hamiltonian graph of degree at least 3 as another cycle of length at least $n−1$, because if we delete an edge in not in an hamiltonian cycle, contracting the same edge will also imply that we can find another cycle of length greater than $n-1$. The counter-example I thought found was in fact not a counter-example.

Comment: @caduc, In any case this is interesting. You couldn't give an exact reference to the relevant paper by Thomassen, I would add this remark to my question.

Comment: On the Number of Hamiltonian Cycles in Bipartite Graphs, section 4 problem 1 https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/953805857C315F92EDD9C75DD58B82F7/S0963548300002182a.pdf/on-the-number-of-hamiltonian-cycles-in-bipartite-graphs.pdf

Comment: @caduk thank you. I have added a reference to Thomassen to my answer.